# Anonymous structures, unions in C99 Keil MDK5

Tags: c, structure, c99, unions, keil

I'm trying to make a big chunk of data more manageable.

```
#pragma anon_unions

typedef union
{
        uint8_t Contents[PACKET_SIZE];

        struct
        {
            uint8_t Command;
            uint8_t X[24];
            uint8_t Y[24];
            uint8_t Z[16];
            uint8_t something;
            .
            .
            .


        };

        struct
        {
            uint8_t Command; // have to rename to dummy_Command to avoid compiler error
            uint8_t A;
            uint8_t B[6];
            uint8_t C[48];
            .
            .
            .

        };
} PacketToFromFile;
```

Is there a way to still use the same name e.g 'Command' without any compiler error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps...

```
#pragma anon_unions

typedef union {
        uint8_t Contents[PACKET_SIZE];

        struct {
            uint8_t Command;
            union {
                struct {
                    uint8_t X[24];
                    uint8_t Y[24];
                    uint8_t Z[16];
                    uint8_t something;
                      :
                      :
                };
                struct {
                    uint8_t A;
                    uint8_t B[6];
                    uint8_t C[48];
                      :
                      :
               };
        }
    }
} PacketToFromFile;
```

I don't have a Keil compiler, but I think this should work.

Comment: It is actually much more complicated than what it is in the question. But your answer gave me the idea to work around it. It works. Thanks @SGeorgiades